# Application_Error not firing in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

All i want to do is simply log any unhandled exceptions in my application:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var logger = new Logger();
        var ex = Server.GetLastError();
        logger.LogError(ex, "global");
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/Index" />
```

When i call

```
throw new Exception("testy");
```

in `HomeController`, the `Application_Error` does not fire.

What is the point of this method? Have I got this confused?

Comment: Looks like you still have to write a response or redirect to your error page, see: [Microsoft: Complete example for error handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx).

Comment: Do you have `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute())` in your `RegisterGlobalFilters` method?

Comment: @Bassie I tried the same code with your throw and it ended up in the Application_Error method. I'm assuming you've stepped through this? If you remove the logger code and set a breakpoint on the Server method call, does it hit?